# Manually implementing @property

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

When manually implementing @property instead of using @synthesize, do you have to include ARC code?

Would it be ok to implement it like this:

```
@synthesize var1;

- (void)setvar1:(NSObject *)newVar1
{
    var1 = newVar1;
}
```

or do you have to include `retain`, `release` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under ARC, you don't have to (and in fact cannot) manually `retain` or `release` variables. Your implementation, apart from needing a capital V in `setVar1:`, is perfectly acceptable under ARC.

Answer (score 1):

When using ARC, you *cannot* write code that manually uses `retain`, `release`, and so on. Therefore, if you choose to implement your property getters and setters manually, and you have ARC enabled, you don't have to include that extra memory management code.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "ARC code" (`retain`, `release`, etc.) is actually manual reference counting, not automatic.

If you are compiling with no ARC, you need to `retain` or copy the object as required. If you are under ARC, the compiler will take care of it for you. Specifically, the compiler will retain `newVar1` if `var1` is declared `__strong`.